# callback jquery plugin printThis

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-callback, printthis

I was trying to find a solution by using this search and google, but I couldn't find anything and I hope you can help me.

I'm using the printThis plugin for print only parts of my page (in my case a DIV=modal dialog). Plugin-Page: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

After the print-dialog is called and I printed the document I want to close my modal dialog automatically, but therefore I need a callback function.

So that's the code which is working for printing:

```
$(".printable").printThis({
             debug: false,
             printContainer: false,
             pageTitle: $("#info-modal .short-info .panel-headline-wrapper h1").html(),
             formValues: true,
             printDelay: 0
            })
```

Now I thought I add a "done()" function from jquery which "catches" the callback...
I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$(".printable").printThis({
            debug: false,
            printContainer: false,
            pageTitle: $("#info-modal .short-info .panel-headline-wrapper h1").html(),
            formValues: true,
            printDelay: 0
        }).done(function(n){
            //close modal dialog
        });
```

I found something in the pull requests: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/pull/28
But I don't know how I can use it.

I'm using the latest version of printThis (v 1.4) and jquery (v 1.11.0)

thank you very much.

cheers,
Marco

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the printThis plugin.

Due to the nature of the print dialog, your current setup won't work, because there is no event tied to the print dialog (when it's fired, done, etc.). Additionally, `$.done` is part of a deferred object, or promise. It won't work in this context.

I haven't yet tested the pull request, but it 'might' work because the browser probably halts and stacks javascript execution while the print dialog is open. However, I don't know how this works across browsers.

If you look in the pull request, the submitter added instructions in the header with the other instructions. You essentially put a function in the config object.

There is another option. You can simply close the modal on the same click event you are using to trigger the print functionality. This approach would be simpler, until I figure out a way to effectively incorporate callbacks.

Comment: Hey Jason, thank you very much for your quick answer. I took a look in the commit comment and tried it with a function ("callback: testfunction")...but doesn't work. even inline doesn't work, like: $(".printable").printThis({callback: function(){alert("the print is done...")} });... (tested with firefox 29.0.1)... So I take the soltion as you mentioned to close the modal dialog with the same click on print :-) thanks so far. If you have another solution, I would be pleased to get an info :-) thank you very much. cheers

Comment: Oh Sorry Jason, I forgot to insert the change (if (typeof opt.callback == 'function') opt.callback.call();) from the commit... now it works!!! (in firefox) so thank you again. cheers marco

Comment: Jason, I am using printThis to print something that I need to be tracked. If I call printThis and the browser dialog comes up, I need know whether the print or cancel was clicked in that dialog. Is there anyway to track this?

Comment: @DougWolfgram - I don't believe there is any way to track that event, as in all of my testing/investigation the browser is blind/halted at that point. I did find an IE event onafterprint (http://help.dottoro.com/ljddsslq.php), but it's useless - triggering when the dialog opens.

Comment: OK. Thanks. We opted for a solution where we prompt the user before bringin up the print dialog that once they go in, it gets flagged for printing. :)